# hide a specific div from html ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am not experimented with ajax.

I have this html ajax response and I want to hide the first div 'loading' after ajax success

Response :

```
<div id="loading">
  <label>..</label>
  <div>...</div>
</div>
<div id="list">
...
...
</div>
```

I have tried a lot of things :

```
success: function (response) {
  response.find('#loading').html().hide();
  response.filter('#loading').hide();
  response.find('#loading').hide();
}
```

But that does not work.

Comment: Did you check Dev console for any errors?  Put a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Directly hide the object by its id:

```
$('#loading').hide()
```

Comment: Could the question be incomplete then? Could you create a fiddle?

Comment: yes, this only works if you do it after you added your content to the dom. see below how to manipulate before adding it

Comment: There is no indication that the div is loaded dynamically?

Comment: there is: "I have this html ajax response ..."

Comment: Maybe :) But How a dynamically loaded html can display a "Loading" message while ajax is loading it?

Comment: the div with id=loading is coming with the ajax response after success

Comment: And you are trying to hide it right there in success handler? Than it is already attached in the DOM at that point means you can hide it as the answer says.

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

js:

```
$.ajax({})
  .done(function(data){
    var html = $(data);
    html.find('#loading').addClass('hidden');
    $('document').append(html);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="loading">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
<button onclick="test()"/>

<script>
  function test() {
document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Nope, the div witch id=loading is coming with the ajax response after success

Answer (score 0):

you must add your response in DOM:

```
$(body).html(response);
```

then you can hide you div :

```
$("#loading").hide();
```